# does ng-repeat create multiple instances of a variable?

Tags: angularjs

I've created this plunker in the form of a 'ToDo' list. My purpose is to fulfill just what it looks like.

Click an item and it will become 'marked' complete. However I am seeing a weird occurrence happen and that is when I change the 'visible' variable to true or false on click, it only effects the list item in the ng-repeat. Conversely, in my 'ToDo' list without ng-repeat the behavior works as expected (though not as desired).

Why does it function this way?

(also the select element at the bottom would work, however it breaks the 'marking complete' by switching the value of 'visible' when I don't actually want it to, any ideas on that would be helpful as well)

http://plnkr.co/edit/uiirZNV5yyBuB5XLst6y?p=preview

```
<h2>using ng-repeat:</h2>
<div ng-init="peeps = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
]"></div>
<ul ng-init="visible = true">
  <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}" ng-repeat="peep in peeps">{{peep.name}}</li>
</ul>
<h2>NOT using ng-repeat:</h2>
<div>
  <ul ng-init="visible = true">
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[0].name}}</li>
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[1].name}}</li>
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[2].name}}</li>
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[3].name}}</li>
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[4].name}}</li>
    <li ng-click="visible = !visible" ng-class="{'strike': !visible, 'none': visible}">{{peeps[5].name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `ng-repeat` creates its own scope for each item,
you need to access parent scope via `$parent`

`ng-repeat` also gives you access to elemnt index in the array,
so your code may look like

```
ng-repeat="(i, peep) in peeps"
...
ng-click="$parent.peeps[i].visible = !$parent.peeps[i].visible"
```

Comment: so each list item will have it's own scope?